# Can we write functional tests using junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testng

I understand Junit is intended for unit testing. Can we write functional tests using junit as well? Like we write Integration tests using junit.

If functional tests are not going to be read by a non-tech user (aka customer) then it looks like a overkill to use tools such as Cucumber, Fitnesse etc. Given that I have a good knowledge of Junits - i want to reuse the same?

Also I notice it is possible to write functional tests using TestNG - Is it a good idea if junit is not suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write any sort of test using junit. for example have a look at [arquillian](http://arquillian.org/), which can boot a whole j2ee container from junit for testing, or [fest](https://code.google.com/p/fest/), which enables swing UI testing from within junit, or use a [selenium junit4 runner](http://selenium-junit4-runner.btmatthews.com/) to test web applications from junit (combine with arquillian to boot the web application 1st :-) )